# Tensorflow, can not figure out what shape my inputs and labels have

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to load weights and for that to work i need to perform the following:

```py
dummy_input = tf.random.uniform(input_shape) # create a tensor of input shape
dummy_label = tf.random.uniform(label_shape) # create a tensor of label shape
hist = model.fit(dummy_input, dummy_label)
```

I am new to this and can't figure out what these shapes should be.
Some information about my model:
Im feeding the model images with shape (224,224,3).
In batches of 16.
I have 423 different classes and use sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

I tried this

```py
dummy_input = tf.random.uniform([16, 224, 224, 3]) # create a tensor of input shape
dummy_label = tf.random.uniform([16, 1, 423]) # create a tensor of label shape
hist = model.fit(dummy_input, dummy_label, epochs=epochs,
  steps_per_epoch=len_train // batch_size,
  validation_steps=len_test // batch_size)
```

There may be many errors here but the one i am getting right now is

```py
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (423,))
should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 423)).
```

Comment: please add `model.summary()` output to the question

Comment: @Andrey I was able to figure this out. But i am still facing problems with loading the model. Please look at my new question if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution

```py
dummy_input = tf.random.uniform([32, 224, 224, 3]) # create a tensor of input shape
dummy_label = tf.random.uniform([32,]) # create a tensor of label shape
hist = model.fit(dummy_input, dummy_label)
```